cuelang: problem when using Reference with regexp
I have a little bit complicated validation rule.
There is a json-file with two structures inside. And depending on data in one structure I validate data in the second one.
Without regexp all works as expected.
json with data to be validated - data.json:
{
  "file-1.yml": {
    "list1": [
      "obj_foo",
      "not_obj_bar",
      "not_obj_zzz"
    ]
  },
  "struct": {
    "someapp": {
      "foo": {"foo1": "foo2"},
      "bar": {"1": "2"},
      "not_zzz": {"aaa": "bbb"}
    }
  }
}

cue rules without regexp - noregexp.cue:
package cue_rules

import "list"

{ ...
  struct?: {
    someapp?: {
      foo?: {...},
      bar?: {...},
      zzz?: {...}
    }
  }

  ["file-1.yml"]: {
    list1="list1"!: [...]
    ...
    if struct.someapp.foo != null {
      "ERROR: object_foo does not exist": list.Contains(list1,"obj_foo") & true
    }
    if struct.someapp.bar != null {
      "ERROR: object_bar does not exist": list.Contains(list1,"obj_bar") & true
    }
    if struct.someapp.zzz != null {
      "ERROR: object_zzz does not exist": list.Contains(list1,"obj_zzz") & true
    }
  }
}

All working fine:
$ cue vet data.json noregexp.cue
"file-1.yml"."ERROR: object_bar does not exist": conflicting values true and false:
    ./noregexp.cue:5:1
    ./noregexp.cue:14:19
    ./noregexp.cue:20:5
    ./noregexp.cue:21:43
    ./noregexp.cue:21:76

But if I want to use instead of "someapp" something like "qwerty-123.456-app" or "asdfgh-000.111-app" , I have to use regex: ".+app".
cue rules with regexp - withregexp.cue:
package cue_rules

import "list"

{ ...
  struct?: {
    ".+app"?: {
      foo?: {...},
      bar?: {...},
      zzz?: {...}
    }
  }

  ["file-1.yml"]: {
    list1="list1"!: [...]
    ...
    if "struct..+app.foo" != null {
      "ERROR: object_foo does not exist": list.Contains(list1,"obj_foo") & true
    }
    if "struct..+app.bar" != null {
      "ERROR: object_bar does not exist": list.Contains(list1,"obj_bar") & true
    }
    if "struct..+app.zzz" != null {
      "ERROR: object_zzz does not exist": list.Contains(list1,"obj_zzz") & true
    }
  }
}

And here I get extra error: "file-1.yml"."ERROR: object_zzz does not exist": conflicting values true and false. This "If" must not be executed, because "struct..+app" does not contain "zzz" object.
$ cue vet data.json withregexp.cue
"file-1.yml"."ERROR: object_bar does not exist": conflicting values true and false:
    ./withregexp.cue:5:1
    ./withregexp.cue:14:19
    ./withregexp.cue:20:5
    ./withregexp.cue:21:43
    ./withregexp.cue:21:76
"file-1.yml"."ERROR: object_zzz does not exist": conflicting values true and false:
    ./withregexp.cue:5:1
    ./withregexp.cue:14:19
    ./withregexp.cue:23:5
    ./withregexp.cue:24:43
    ./withregexp.cue:24:76

May be cue interprets "struct..+app.zzz" as string and that's why trying to execute following statement.
How to correctly write "if" statement to cue recognize it as a structure, not as a string?
Tried to use aliases, but no success.
